# How to activate app from keyboard if disabled from ctrl-tab (app switcher) on MAC OS X Yosemite (LSUIElement)

Tags: macos, plist, osx-yosemite

**10.10 Yosemite Mac OS X**

**(info.plist)**

**Before/Default**

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
```

Example:'**LaunchBar**' application works with Tab the command key twice as a shortcut to activate LaunchBar

**After**

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Or

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>true</string>
```

tab the command key double (tab twice) doesn't work

Comment: What's a double-command key?  I've been using Macs since 1984 and have never heard of that.

Comment: I have made more clear, thanks